# How to correctly use the mysql DISTINCT?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select all rows and columns of a table, but I don't want to select rows that contain the same tokens.
Example:

id 1, token 4567, name chris, text hello 
id 2, token 4567, name chris, text great 
id 3, token 1234, name luan, text hi

**What have I tried:**

`` "SELECT DISTINCT token, name, email, text, status FROM `chatMessages` " ``

- return: token 4567,4567,1234

**My problem:**
The code above is returning the different text values, but I just wanted it to return the different tokens

**My wish:**

- return: token 4567,1234

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results *as text tables*.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT token` is going to retrieve only the rows where `token` is distinct, I really don't understand why your query is not working as expected.

Comment: @cristi_nmr  It's as if he were saying like this, select different values ​​for token and also for name and also for email and status, as I'm very new to mysql I don't understand the error either

Comment: Why would you rather choose the rows `1, 3` rather than `2, 3` ?

Comment: @cristi_nmr My wish would be something like, SELECT DISTINCT token, and get all the data from that row FROM chatmessages, but I don't think that exists, I'll parse the Gordon code

Comment: @cid is not even line 1, 3, it would only be the different lines, for example, 3 tokens (users) are in this table, but there are 100 ids in this table, so do not select all ids, select only the different tokens each id of the 100 has one of the 3 tokens, but select only the 3 tokens

Comment: @Godofallwars I'm fine with selecting distinct tokens, but in your example, you're selecting other fields, such as `text` which differs even if the token is the same. So, what's the logic behind getting `'hello'` over `'great'` ? If you just want to get the tokens, you can simply do `SELECT DISTINCT token FROM ...`

Comment: @cid The problem is that I want to get this from the table: `token, name, email, status`.
So far so good, but I don't want to get all the rows from this table, I just want to get the rows where the token are distinct

Comment: @cid if the token is different you take it, ignoring the name, email, status, etc.

Comment: @cid This is my problem, I don't want to get just the token, I want to get the token, and the other data, but I don't want it to select the rows that contain the same token

Comment: @cid I rephrased the question for better understanding

Comment: @Godofallwars I don't think you mentioned the MySQL version  `SELECT version();` 
 Gordon has an answer, but it uses syntax for MySQL 8+.  If you have an older version, you'll need to replace the window function logic.

Comment: @JonArmstrong Gordon's code didn't work for me `Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MySQL
Server connection: SSL is not being used Documentation
Server version: 5.7.26 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version: 10
User: root@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)` I think mine should be 5.7

Comment: MySQL 5.7 doesn't support window functions.  This can be done other ways too.

Comment: @JonArmstrong Could you help me with my version?

Comment: I picked the `MIN(id)` per `token`.  Adjust as needed.

Comment: People keep asking, and you keep misunderstanding the question: How do you want to decide which row to get the other fields from when a token appears more than once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MySQL 5.7, here's one approach:

```
SELECT t1.*
  FROM chatmessages AS t1
 WHERE (token, id) IN
         (SELECT token, MIN(id) FROM chatmessages GROUP BY token)
;
```

Comment: I will analyze the code and read more about what you used, but it worked, thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want one arbitrary row per token, you can use window functions:

```
select cm.*
from (select cm.*,
             row_number() over (partition by token order by rand()) as seqnum
      from chatmessages cm
     ) cm
where seqnum = 1;
```

The `order by rand()` returns a *random* row for each token.  If you have one in mind -- the newest, oldest, or whatever -- then adjust the `order by` clause.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL 5.6 approach...

If you're still looking for a way to use the `DISTINCT` statement, you can do this using the `GROUP BY` approach below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT MIN(t.id) AS id, t.token, t.name, t.text
FROM `chatMessages` AS t
GROUP BY `token` DESC
```

Trying with the sample data below

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `chatMessages` (
  `id` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `token` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `text` varchar(200) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `chatMessages` (`id`, `token`, `name`, `text`) VALUES
  ('1', '4567', 'chris', 'hello'),
  ('2', '4567', 'chris', 'great'),
  ('3', '1234', 'luan', 'hi');
```

Will return this

| id | token | name | text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4567 | chris | hello |
| 3 | 1234 | luan | hi |

Here's an example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/99afcd/7)

Comment: This isn't valid SQL, even though MySQL can be configured to allow it. With newer versions of MySQL (like 5.7) the default behavior will spot the problem and generate an error: `Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'db_1940092091.t.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: Here's the test case: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=711e9767922ddbb81a0ef7026f12f507

Comment: Here are some helpful sources of information about `GROUP BY` and `Functional Dependence`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html    AND  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html

Comment: @Nathan although it's a great explanation it was the first thing I tried too, but I got an error, Jon's solution worked, anyway thank you